# Google App Script Spreadsheets: adding new series to plot from code

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-visualization

I have a SpreadSheet where I have 4 columns of data and a scatter plot, where the first column serves as the X axis, and the other 3 columns are series to be represented.

So, when I set this up in a spreadsheet without any code, it works and the series are shown.

Now I want to add 3 more series. So I am copying columns B, C and D to columns E, F and G (they will be repeated, but for this test it will be ok). I am doing this when a button is pressed:

```
function test() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var rangeToCopy = sheet.getRange(20, 2, 219, 4);
  rangeToCopy.copyTo(sheet.getRange(20, 5));

  var series_settings = [
    {'color': 'blue', 'labelInLegend' : 'Serie1', 'lineWidth': 1, 'pointSize': 0},
    {'color': 'red',  'labelInLegend' : 'Serie2',     'lineWidth': 1, 'pointSize': 0},
    {'color': 'purple',  'labelInLegend' : 'Serie3', 'lineWidth': 1, 'pointSize': 0}
  ]

  series_settings.push({'color': 'turquoise',  'labelInLegend' : 'Serie4', 'lineWidth': 1, 'pointSize': 0, 'lineDashStyle': [4, 4]});
  series_settings.push({'color': 'orange',  'labelInLegend' : 'Serie5', 'lineWidth': 1, 'pointSize': 0});
  series_settings.push({'color': 'plum',  'labelInLegend' : 'Serie6', 'lineWidth': 1, 'pointSize': 0});

  var charts = sheet.getCharts();
  chart = charts[0];
  chartBuilder = chart.modify();
  chartBuilder = chartBuilder.clearRanges();
  chartBuilder = chartBuilder.addRange(sheet.getRange(20, 1, 200, 7));
  chartBuilder = chartBuilder.setOption('series', series_settings);
  chart = chartBuilder.build();
  sheet.updateChart(chart);
}
```

About the magic numbers: data is composed by 200 rows starting in row number 20, and as said before is composed by 7 columns (x axis in A, 3 columns of series in BCD, and the copy of those 3 series in EFG).

So, when I press the button, only column E is shown, but all series are correctly shown in the legend. I tried it in [this file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UW5ALdGiJJ7pokq7tzNRpQ7yZkfKRgBccOTpYA1vWR0/edit?usp=sharing):
[image]

Obviously, this file is a short example to post here. In my project, the behavior is slightly different: the 3 first series are correctly shown, but the 3 copies are invisible in the chart, despite they appear in the legend.

Any idea of what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm testing the sheet you shared and after pressing the button it does actually display the other columns for what I can see, at leas series 5 & 6, they just have the same values as series 4, so they're all overlapping each other. If the copies in your project have the same value then they will also overlap like this, making you not see them

Comment: @AMolina In the other project, I make the copy of the columns, and then modify the columns BCD (so I can compare against the previous execution), so they should not overlap. Here I wrote it like this just to simplify the example, and since I wanted to show that I am using the copy function just to be sure that is not the source of the problem. In this example, columns are being copied, but not being shown in the chart. I can only see the series 4 (I will add an snapshot to the question)

Comment: I think I just figured it out, you're setting `pointSize = 0` in all cases, so it won't be displayed, it's basically an empty line, if you give it a value it actually shows the points.

Comment: @AMolina it does work, but I do like the way it looks when pointsize=0 and therefore only the line going through the points is shown... I will take it if no other solution can be provided, but it is strange

Comment: Maybe you can set a small size, like `0.1` to see if it looks more like a line, while making the whole thing more visible.